# Fontnames containing comma in one context and hyphen in another

Tags: itext, acrobat

If I create a PDF using Acrobat Professional 9, containing a single sentence and make that sentence "Georgia Bold", then save, I end up with a PDF that references the font "Georgia,Bold".

If I then take that font from c:\windows\fonts\georgiab.ttf and interrogate it using the following code and itext 4.2, I end up with a font name of "Georgia-Bold"

```
   String path = "georgiab.ttf";
   BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont( path, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED );
   System.out.println( "Font " + baseFont.getPostscriptFontName() + " found in " +  path );
```

I'm trying to determine why when used in a PDF file, the font name has a comma whereas when used outside of a PDF file, the font name has a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name that you get from `getPostscriptFontName()` is the actual name within the font file. For a TrueType font this is parsed in the `BaseFont` method of `TrueTypeFont.java` ([line 498 in 5.1.1.3](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/TrueTypeFont.java?revision=5012&view=markup#l498)).

Why does Adobe use a comma? That's just what they decided to use. If I were to guess they probably chose the comma because some fonts use hyphens in their name but most (if any at all) never use a comma. So instead of `My-Awesome-Font-Bold` they chose `My-Awesome-Font,Bold`. Users can tell that they're using a bold variant of a font instead of just a font that happens to have the word "bold" in it.

Comment: Based on your answer, I believe that if I want to match up an installed font "Georgia" with a font referenced in the PDF "Georgia,Bold", I can strip the ",Bold" portion then and apply bold as an attribute?

Comment: I think so but I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "attribute". Are you talking about HTML or something similar where you specify a base font with additional details such as "bold" and/or "italic"?

Comment: In iText, using the FontFactory.getFont("Georgia", 14, Font.BOLD)